# I want to build Magento extension for enterprise edition. For this how can I setup development environment for enterprise?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento-2-commerce, custom-extension

I want to build a Magento extension for the enterprise edition. For this how can I set up a development environment for the enterprise?  and how can I get an enterprise edition license? Do we need to purchase a license for the development purpose as well or is there any way we can setup a development environment for the enterprise edition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes public and private key is required for the enterprise magento version, at the installation time. You can test your module that you have developed on the CE version directly.

Comment: Abhay Agrawal, How can I get the public and private keys? Do I need to purchase those keys?
If yes please let me know the process from where I can purchase.